# membership provider, change password returning false

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership, membership

Is there any way to get the full message response from the changepassword method? I need to find out why it's returning false. It never has in the past, the current password is correct and so is the emailresponse variable.

```
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(emailresponse);
bool changed = u.ChangePassword("Password~123", txtPassword.Text);
if (changed){                              
         //code emitted                      
}
```

Comment: Which Membership provider are you using? Maybe the new password is too short or in some other way not allowed?

Comment: @D.R. System.Web.Security.Membership  I thought about that, but I need to figure out how to get the message from the Change Password method to know for sure.

Comment: I found the reason, the password has to be over 7 chars and include a non alpha charactor. But if someone still wants to answer this question it will help future programmers get the response reasoning.

Comment: There does not seem to be a programmatic way. One could check the source of MembershipUser at http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/Security/MembershipUser@cs/1/MembershipUser@cs for more information or just debug into ChangePassword().